# How should you view it when company ask whether you are passionate but when you join, everybody just treat it as "just a job"?

Tags: job-search

How should you view it when during the interview process, the recruiting department asks as if you should be passionate about the job, and find the job meaningful, but when you join, everybody just treat it as just a job, or just something to do to get a paycheck?

Comment: What do you mean by "how should you view it?" You should probably make up your own mind about how *you* feel about your employer. You may want to look through the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) to get some ideas about how to phrase your question.  As is, this is is really speculative and hard to answer conclusively.

Comment: It's something every company says. CEOs all stand up and say "Our employees are the smartest, the best trained and the most passionate". You don't take them seriously any more than the politician who says "I'm unquestionably going to win this election" or the advert that says "Our product is the best".

Comment: You should view it as a company trying to correct itself. That's it. The less their workers are passionate, the more they're going to try to find passionate workers. That is just how it works.

Answer (score 4):

**Companies are deluding themselves when hiring**

You should view it as a company being aspirational and tricking itself as that is all it is. Most people fake passion during the interview, so companies come to demand it as they can get it. After hiring, they never check for it again.

Answer (score 1):

> but when you join, everybody just treat it as just a job, or just something to do to get a paycheck?

Welcome to the workforce! Every company out there makes it sound like they are into the latest cutting edge stuff like you're going to be living and breathing whatever it is they're into. At my last company they act like drilling into web site log data and page views were the latest and greatest thing that ever happened and the workers are spending all day building crazy graphs and correlating massive data set as if they're figuring out everything there is about their user. Reality is all we did was parse the data string and made it as an option. Rest of the time was spent pluging in data by copy-and-pasting one javascript into a different page and just changing the strings and ids. Takes 2 minutes to do.